# PDF stitch pages

Tags: pdf, adobe

I want to stitch (merge/combine) the pages of one PDf to one page.

In the **one** PDF file are 3 pages and I want that there is only one long page - with no page breaks.

I **did not** want to merge 3 files in one! That's easy and you can find it anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do: `cpdf -impose-xy "1 0" in.pdf -o out.pdf`. This is 1 page across, and 0 pages down - 0 is used to indicate an unknown number. And so, all the pages will be merged into one long page.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to cpdf is [pdfcpu](https://pdfcpu.io/) (note the syntax is different but grid result should be the same).

[image]

bo is the flag for add border between pages, 3 is the vertical and 1 is the horizontal

```
pdfcpu grid -- "bo:off" out.pdf 3 1 in.pdf
```

see https://pdfcpu.io/generate/grid#examples